# ChildProcess.fork not using babel arguments

Tags: node.js, child-process

I seem to be having an issue with Node's built in process forking function. I have a project that is using babel-register and launched using `node -r babel-register app.js`, and am trying to fork a child process in the same manner. I have the following code that doesn't seem to be working, and in addition it gives me an error saying `bad option: -r`.

```
const proc = fork(
  `${__dirname}/window.js`,
  {
    execArgv: ['-r babel-register']
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try listing the arguments `execArgv` as an [array](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) `['-r', 'babel-register']`.

```
const proc = fork(
    `${__dirname}/window.js`,
    {
      execArgv: ['-r', 'babel-register']
    }
);
```

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, worked after I changed it: '@babel-register'